# Распарсить XML-файл

Tags: xml, php

Есть xml:

```
<response>
<result-code fatal="false">0</result-code>
<bills-list>
<bill id="1380271108" status ="60" error="0" sum="0.20" />
</bills-list>
</response>
```

Как получить `status` или `sum`?

`result-code` получил, а на остальное ума видимо не хватает:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
  $retval = $xml->result-code;

  echo $retval;
```

Comment: var_dump() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php 
    $xmls = '<response>
    <result-code fatal="false">0</result-code>
    <bills-list>
    <bill id="1380271108" status ="60" error="0" sum="0.20" />
    </bills-list>
    </response>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmls);

    $bl = "bills-list";
    echo "id " . (int)$xml->$bl->bill[0]["id"] ."\n";
    echo "status " . (int)$xml->$bl->bill[0]["status"] ."\n";
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/a0CfQu)

[simplexmlelement.attributes.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo "<pre>";
Var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

Ну и смотри что у тебя где лежит.